# Enable XML Menu Option in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, xsd

I'm using Visual studio 2012. There XML Menu option is missing.

I'm trying to create XSD, based on my sample XML.

I tried to find menu options.

How do i enable the XML menu?

Any Settings need to be changed? Or Do i need to install any extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drag and drop your XML file to VS2012 and then you will see the XML menu. It only shows if you add an XML file to VS2012

Comment: you can add any helpful link which has shown same in images

Comment: Yeah that's correct. I did that long back. Forgot to add as an answer. Thanks for the answer. :)