# Enable XML Menu Option in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 (community version) and I can't display XML menu.

I searched and found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035401/enable-xml-menu-option-in-visual-studio-2012), but answer proposed is not working for 2019 version.

How can I enable it?

Purpose is to create XML Schema with the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Open Microsoft Visual Studio then on the File menu, point to New, and click File.

Select XML File in the Templates panel and click Open.

Now you can see XML menu.

Comment: Yes, the XML menu is visible as soon as you open a file in the XML editor of visual studio. Simply by opening an XML file or creating a new one. Tested with VS Enterprise 2019.